# SQL Server / Azure DB - adding an JOIN slows query by seconds for only 180~ rows

Tags: sql-server, azure

I have the following:

**Query**:

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON;
GO

SELECT * 
FROM dbo.BidReviewCase
JOIN dbo.AnprEvent ON AnprEvent.Id = BidReviewCase.AnprEventId
JOIN dbo.Camera ON Camera.Id = AnprEvent.CameraId -- << SLOW JOIN HERE
SET STATISTICS TIME OFF
```

## Execution Plan

[image]

## Related Schema

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BidReviewCase] (
    [CaseId]                   INT              IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [AnprEventId]              INT              NOT NULL,
    [Summary]                  NVARCHAR (MAX)   NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_BidReviewCase] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CaseId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_BidReviewCase_AnprEvent_AnprEventId] FOREIGN KEY ([AnprEventId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AnprEvent] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Camera] (
[Id]          INT              IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[CameraName]  NVARCHAR (MAX)   NOT NULL,
[SiteId]      INT              NOT NULL,
[NvrIp]       NVARCHAR (MAX)   NULL,
[NvrPassword] NVARCHAR (MAX)   NULL,
[NvrPort]     NVARCHAR (MAX)   NULL,
[NvrUsername] NVARCHAR (MAX)   NULL,
[ChannelA]    NVARCHAR (MAX)   NULL,
[ChannelB]    NVARCHAR (MAX)   NULL,
[Reference]   UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Camera] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Camera_Site_SiteId] FOREIGN KEY ([SiteId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Site] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AnprEvent] (
[Id]              INT              IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[DateTimeRead]    DATETIME2 (7)    NOT NULL,
[Reference]       UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
[Registration]    NVARCHAR (MAX)   NOT NULL,
[CameraId]        INT              DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
[Country]         INT              DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
[DateTimeCreated] DATETIME2 (7)    NULL,
[Direction]       INT              DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
[EventReference]  UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') NOT NULL,
[LaneId]          INT              DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
[Region]          INT              DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_AnprEvent] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_AnprEvent_Camera_CameraId] FOREIGN KEY ([CameraId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Camera] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [AnprEventCameraId]
ON [dbo].[AnprEvent]([CameraId] ASC)
INCLUDE([Id]);
```

## Row Counts

AnprEventCount: 5676

BidReviewCaseCount: 176

CameraCount: 2

## Problem

The above query takes `3-4` seconds and by removing the camera JOIN it then takes about `5ms`

I discovered I can change my `JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN` and it fixes the issue. However I am querying this using `EntityFramework` which will be using `INNER JOINS`.

I have no idea what is causing this behaviour. Any advice in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide `DDL` for `dbo.BidReviewCase`. Also question from another area... `SELECT *` is necessary in your case?

Comment: How many rows are there approximately?

Comment: Just added them to the question: AnprEventCount: 5676

BidReviewCaseCount: 176

CameraCount: 2

Comment: Select * is appropriate as EntityFramework will be generating a similar query

Comment: Your row counts are really not that big :-) glad that you Maxim could solve this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try updating statistics on tables involved with `update statistics` command.

The thing is the engine righteously thinks that it's cheaper to join smaller tables first and then join the result with the dependent table. Add an index on anpreventid field, this should speed up the query

Comment: I just ran the command `UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.Camera` and this resolved the issue. It's worth mentioning I'm running on Azure Database. I can't believe it was that simple. Thank you¬

Comment: I will also add the index for AnprEventId on BidReviewCase to improve performance further. Thank you.

Comment: Please have a look at the plan, it might not be used at all with your current data. When tables grow server might revert back to original plan and then the index would be useful